# Why do I get 'There is no timestamp for /base/src/tests/core/types.tests!'?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner

I'm trying to figure it out for few hours and I guess that it has to do with my misconfigured requirejs file ('test.main.js') but I'm not quite sure so can someone please explain to me what's wrong?

If you need more information from me I'd be happy to provide it.

**Here is the output of the stack trace.**

```
Eyal Shilony@LIONKING /d/Projects/Code/Development/tsToolkit
$ ./karma.sh start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:8380/
INFO [IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket GCSNAkUAY24F-MN7dkGQ with id manual-4464
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/src/tests/core/types.tests!'

WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/src/tests/core/types.tests
IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Script error for: /base/src/tests/core/types.tests
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
  at D:/Projects/Code/Development/tsToolkit/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
```

**Here is the directory structure I'm using atm.**

```
.
|-- WebEssentials-Settings.json
|-- jake.sh
|-- jakefile.js
|-- karma.sh
|-- node_modules
|   |-- jake
|   |   |-- Jakefile
|   |   |-- Makefile
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- bin
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   `-- test
|   |-- jasmine-node
|   |   |-- Gruntfile.coffee
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- bin
|   |   |-- bower.json
|   |   |-- index.js
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- scripts
|   |   |-- spec
|   |   `-- src
|   |-- karma
|   |   |-- CHANGELOG.md
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- bin
|   |   |-- config.tpl.coffee
|   |   |-- config.tpl.js
|   |   |-- config.tpl.ls
|   |   |-- karma-completion.sh
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   |-- node_modules
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- requirejs.config.tpl.coffee
|   |   |-- requirejs.config.tpl.js
|   |   `-- static
|   |-- karma-jasmine
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   `-- package.json
|   |-- karma-requirejs
|   |   |-- LICENSE
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- lib
|   |   `-- package.json
|   |-- karma-requirejs-preprocessor
|   |   `-- index.js
|   |-- requirejs
|   |   |-- README.md
|   |   |-- bin
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   `-- require.js
|   `-- shelljs
|       |-- LICENSE
|       |-- README.md
|       |-- bin
|       |-- global.js
|       |-- make.js
|       |-- package.json
|       |-- scripts
|       |-- shell.js
|       `-- src
|-- scratchpad.txt
|-- src
|   |-- app.main.js
|   |-- app.main.js.map
|   |-- app.main.ts
|   |-- framework
|   |   |-- core
|   |   |-- css
|   |   `-- widgets
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- libs
|   |   |-- jquery-2.1.0.js
|   |   |-- require.js
|   |   `-- typings
|   |-- tests
|   |   |-- core
|   |   `-- test.main.js
|   |-- tsToolkit.csproj
|   |-- tsToolkit.csproj.user
|   |-- web.Debug.config
|   |-- web.Release.config
|   `-- web.config
|-- tools
|   |-- karma
|   |   |-- karma.conf.js
|   |   `-- karma.conf.js.back
|   `-- mocha
|       `-- mocha.ext.js
|-- tsToolkit.sln
|-- tsToolkit.sln.DotSettings.user
`-- tsToolkit.v12.suo

41 directories, 59 files
```

**Here is the config file for Karma.**

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri May 16 2014 08:27:07 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../../',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            {pattern: 'src/libs/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'src/framework/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'src/tests/**/*tests.js', included: false},
            'src/tests/test.main.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            'src/app.main.js'
        ],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {

        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['progress'],


        // web server port
        port: 8380,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: [],


        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

**and finally here is my 'test.main.js' file to setup requirejs for Karma.**

```
var tests = [];
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        if (/\.tests\.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file.replace(/\.js$/, ""));
        }
    }
}

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    deps: tests,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

Comment: This can also happen if the files don't actually exist, as detailed in [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37259893/26510)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It tooks me few days to figure it out, the paths were incorrect all over the place both in my Karma configuration files and the requirejs 'tests.main.js' file.

So what I did was going to [Karma - RequireJS](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html) tutorial, downloaded the [project](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/karma-requirejs) from github and basically restructure it bit by bit to understand why it doesn't work in my own project.

I had two recurring errors and both of them related to incorrect paths so I posted the [full solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649413/issue-getting-typescript-karma-requirejs-and-chai-to-work-together) in another question that I asked at StackOverflow.

The solution is now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/eyal-archive/TypeScript-RequireJS-And-Karma).